# Ubuntu boot failed

Tags: boot, 13.04

I have Kubuntu 13.04 installed and it was working fine until today, it's failed to boot with mounting failed message.

I've run the [Boot Repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6802016/) but didn't fix my problem.

If anyone can help, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Change Legacy/Bios mode into UEFI mode in bios.
- And then follow the steps given in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_mode) link to convert Ubuntu into EFI mode.

Comment: the problem seems to be fixed, I just installed some updates that was pending.

Comment: you says that you can't able to boot ubuntu then how did you install updates?

Comment: I boot it with startx when I first had the boot failure that's how i manage to run the boot repair